# SQL Server 2008 R2: Is it possible to have transactional replication from one (Master) to 3-4 slave servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication

Is it possible to replicate live DB from SQL Server 2008 R2 acting as master (all writes happens here) to 3-4 independent physical SQL Server 2008 R2 machines?

I do have several additional resources for heavy "SELECT" queries (READS) only

Thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But your design will have to account for latency between write and read: read on a subscriber may not found the data you just wrote on the master. The replication delay can be anything from few milliseconds to minutes, and it can even be hours behind in some bad situations.

If you're OK with the delay (and you must be, since is the only option) then you can consider solutions that have higher latency, but are much easier to maintain, namely [Log Shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx). Log Shipping is easier than Replication because it does not require special handling of DDL changes.

Comment: Log shipping is easier in some respects, harder in others.  For instance, how do you go about reading data from the destination database on a regular basis?  You can use database snapshots or recover with standby, but both of those options require more intervention (and disconnecting clients) when you want to get fresher data to the consumers at the destination.